# Populate array in angularJS model from view

Tags: angularjs

I am building an angularJS on client side and asp.net as backend. I have a aspx repeater that generate html on server side. I want to populate and array of angular model so that it can be used to make client side interactive application.

```
            <div ng-controller="myController">
                    <input type="number"id='1' ng-model="number"/>
                    <input type="number"id='2' ng-model="number"/>
                    <input type="number"id='3' ng-model="number"/>
                    <input type="number"id='4' ng-model="number"/>
                    <input type="number"id='5' ng-model="number"/>                        

            </div>
```

I want to have all the numbers in an array of my model. is it possible to populate model array from the already generated html.

Comment: Im sure it's possible in a hacky way...you should iterate over the data client-side with `ng-repeat` to provide easier Angular interaction

Answer (score 3):

Make $scope.numbers an array and use ng-repeat like this: `$scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];`

In your markup:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat="number in numbers">
                    <input type="number" id="number{number}" ng-model="number"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are generating html code on the server side you can use ngInit to place some data in the scope.
You could write something on the server side:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="myData=[{type:'number', id:1, model:'number1'},{type:'number', id:2, model:'number2'}]">
  <div>{{numbers}}</div>
  <input ng-repeat="item in myData" type="{{item.type}}" id="{{item.id}}" ng-model="numbers[item.model]"/>
</div>
```

and your controller could look like this

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = {};
});
```

Comment: Hi, As i am using asp:repeater and serializing and formatting data like myData=[{type:'number', id:1, model:'number1'},{type:'number', id:2, model:'number2'}] would be an overhead. I am looking for an option that process the html view to populate data in the model.